# How to access codepipeline environment variable to Rails database.yml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, docker-compose, dockerfile, aws-codepipeline

I've added environment variables in AWS Codepipeline build phase. Now when command  `RUN bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production` runs it tries to find production database which looks in database.yml file. I want to access env variables which are added in AWS codepipeline build phase in database.yml.

How may I achieve this? If there is any alternative than also open for it. Please find below files...

Database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: Backend_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: JSMA_Backend_test

production:
  <<: *default
  username: <%= ENV['DATABASE_USER'] %>
  database: <%= ENV['DATABASE_NAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['DATABASE_HOST'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PORT'] %>
```

Dockerfile

```
# Use an official Ruby runtime as a parent image
FROM ruby:3.1-alpine

# Set the working directory in the container to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Install build dependencies
RUN apk update && apk add --virtual build-dependencies build-base

# Install imagemagick
RUN apk add imagemagick

# Install the PostgreSQL client library
RUN apk add postgresql-dev
# Copy the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock from your host machine to the container
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./

# Install RubyGems and Bundler
RUN gem update --system && gem install bundler

# Install the RubyGems specified in the Gemfile
RUN bundle install --without development test


# Copy the rest of your application code from your host machine to the container
COPY . .

RUN bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production

# Start the Rails server
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "server", "-e", "production"]
# CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "server"]
```

Docker-compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: <%= ENV['DATABASE_USER'] %>
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
      POSTGRES_DB: <%= ENV['DATABASE_NAME'] %>
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

buildspec.yml

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - export DATABASE_HOST=$DATABASE_HOST
      - export DATABASE_NAME=$DATABASE_NAME
      - export DATABASE_USER=$DATABASE_USER
      - export DATABASE_PASSWORD=$DATABASE_PASSWORD
      - export DATABASE_PORT=$DATABASE_PORT
      - echo $DATABASE_HOST
      - echo AWS ECR login
      - $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region ap-south-1)
      - REPO_URI=*** repo here
      - COMMIT_HASH=$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | cut -c 1-7)
      - IMAGE_TAG=${COMMIT_HASH:=latest}
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Building docker image
      - docker build -t jsm-rails .
      - docker tag //repo****:latest
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo build successful!
      - echo pushing image to ecr...
      - docker push //repo url here *** rails:latest
      - echo pushed image!
```

If there is any alternative than also open for it.

Answer (score 0):

achieved by adding line in pre-build phase in buildspec.yml

```
   - "sed -i \"s/production:/production:\\n  url: postgres:\\/\\/$DATABASE_USER:$DATABASE_PASSWORD@$DATABASE_HOST:$DATABASE_PORT\\/$DATABASE_NAME/\" config/database.yml"
```